# Problem with form size property

Tags: visual-studio

I have a problem with screen size. In my computer, I set form size is 1915*1130. However, when open project in other computer (the same resolution), form size is change into 1910x1020.

2 computer resolutions is set as the same.

Is there any property to prevent that.

Does anyone have the same issue?
Please help me.

Thanks,
Ankata

Answer (score 0):

Try this, http://forums.aspfree.com/visual-studio-how-to-73/windows-form-height-size-cant-be-made-bigger-than-screen-382576.html

He puts a panel control onto the form with scroll bars on. This allows you to set the size of the panel and somehow the form accommodates it. Haven't tried it myself.